# Запятые при сочетании вводных - с союзами и частицами

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Из описания Неаполя:

> ...Ну и в-третьих, и быть может, в главных – тут ведь с первой минуты
>   на губах ощущаешь соль… Не знаю, мне кажется, морские города – они
>   особенные.

Ума не приложу, как ещё расставить знаки.

*Ну и в-третьих и, быть может, в главных?..* - что ли так?

Comment: "В-главных" пишется через дефис.

Comment: Спасибо, драгоценный Гриззли! Действительно - прозевала!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ну и в-третьих, и быть может, в-главных – тут ведь с первой минуты на губах ощущаешь соль… Не знаю, мне кажется, морские города – они особенные.**

Пояснение

1) Тесная связь союза И  и вводного слова

6. Между присоединительным союзом (в начале самостоятельного предложения) и вводным словом (сочетанием) запятая обычно не ставится, так как **союз тесно примыкает к вводному слову:** И может быть, результаты будут вполне удовлетворительные; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Пример:

**И может быть,** унесут к своим далёким очагам нечто такое, что пребудет вовеки. [Сергей Довлатов. Дорога в новую квартиру (1987)]

2) **Всю вводную часть** лучше отделить от основной части **одним тире**, поэтому обособление  ***и, быть может, в-главных*** двумя  тире нежелательно.

Comment: Розенталь говорит о союзе в начале самостоятельного предложения, а у нас?

Comment: Розенталь не мог разобрать абсолютно все конструкции, это практически невозможно, но он часто в своих правилах говорит о возможности примыкания союза И к обособленным структурам в качестве присоединительного союза. Поэтому приходится иногда самостоятельно решать нестандартные задачи. Какие здесь причины для отсутствия тесной связи и что нам дает эта запятая? Союз И здесь явно присоединительный, он повторяет первый присоединительный союз. И на графику обратите внимание: в этой  небольшой по объёму вводной части явный избыток знаков, просто слов не видно  за  запятыми и дефисами.

Comment: Что касается вашего варианта с двумя тире, то такое деление предложения  трудно и прочитать,  и  понять: вводное слово, вставка на основе вводного слова и только потом основное содержание ( и всё это для предложения очень небольшого объёма).

Comment: Набрал в Нацкорпусе "и может быть главное" — нашел 13 вхождений, и везде запятая после *и*, кроме одного (но там тире после *и*). Везде и отделено. Везде схема такая: <знак>и<знак> может быть<знак> главное<>знак. И везде избыток знаков. И никто из этих авторов не трактует Розенталя раширительно.

Comment: Если не ставить два тире, то, следуя примерам, можно первое тире заменить запятой.

Comment: Ну если везде и никто, то конечно. Зачем подставляться, лучше после каждого слова написать запятую, чем толковать Розенталя расширительно. .Правда,  по поводу двух тире у меня всё-таки есть сомнения. Вот попробуем убрать второе вводное: "Ну и в-третьих – тут ведь с первой минуты на губах ощущаешь соль…"  Предложение явно составлено "под тире".  А вы к этому тире добавляете еще и вставку. Как читать-то?

Comment: Хочется,чтобы графика была красивой, а знаки препинания (как ноты в музыке) помогали озвучивать текст, а не только стояли бы по правилам. У меня нет желания  что-то доказывать, но вопрос принципиальный. Можно рассматривать  правила  письма как полностью регламентированную систему,  а можно считать, что в рамках этой системы есть степень свободы, позволяющая выразить нужный оттенок смысла и подобрать подходящее графическое оформление для каждого конкретного случая. Это делает систему правописания устойчивой, дает ей большие потенциальные возможности и защищает от возможного реформаторства.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

**Ну и в-третьих — и, быть может, в-главных — тут ведь с первой минуты на губах ощущаешь соль… Не знаю, мне кажется, морские города – они особенные.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> А во-вторых ― и в-главных ― Ольгин образ в моём сознании двоится, расслаивается, распадается на две части ― до и после. [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

*В-главных* пишется через дефис:

> [§ 138. Пишутся через дефис](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=658#pp658):
>   1. Наречия с приставкой в- (во-), образованные от порядковых числительных, напр.: во-первых, во-вторых, в-третьих, в-десятых (так же пишется **в-главных**, в-последних).

МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ — вводное сочетание, должно обособляться, запятая после союза ставится:

> Запятая после союза ставится, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры.([3. Вводное слово и союз](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2))

Comment: Ну не знаю я, кому дать ЛОшку... Мне нравятся оба варианта - твой и Жасминин; попрошу рассудить автора, спецпросьба к нему такая будет: выбор ЛО.

Answer (score 1):

Если следовать правилам, то, как я вижу, возможны два варианта:

**Ну и в-третьих, и, быть может, в-главных – ...

Ну, и в-третьих, и, быть может, в-главных – ...**

Вот что-то похожее:

***Ну, и, в-третьих,*** впервые в истории на Красную планету командируется космический корабль с пилотами.
***Ну и в-третьих, быть может,*** так скорее наступит день, когда...
 ***Ну и, разумеется, в-третьих,*** не стоит забывать о накопительных скидках.

Мне кажется, что избежать огромного количества знаков поможет такая конструкция (она попроще, но смысл тот же):

**И, в-третьих, самое, быть может, главное – тут ведь с первой минуты на губах ощущаешь соль…**